# Get date format with time zone as added hours

Tags: java, jmeter

How to get the current date time in JMeter formatted like this

```
2021-03-02T07:57:19+01:00
```

I have used `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` but it doesn't format as expected

Comment: What exactly have you tried (code) and what exactly didn't work (exception? doesn't compile? wrong value? wrong formatting?)???

Comment: please read the question carefully. I have written an expectation from a formatting and asked for a more accurate formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), for example with [time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function

```
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX)}
```

[image]

> Z  Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800

> X  Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00

Comment: the result is 2021-03-02T08:35:21+0100 how can i get it to be formatted like 2021-03-02T08:35:21+01:00

Comment: @FarFarAway you can use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`

Comment: works great. thanks